# Get Arjuna source for JBoss

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

How can I get the source code for Arjuna/JBossTM that matches my JBoss version?

More specifically, is there a way to reliably identify the version of a library that is distributed with JBoss 5.1.0?

The options I've tried so far:

- opening the manifest file of jbossjts.jar which gives me 5.1.0
- opening the file `jar-versions.xml`, but that also gives me 5.1.0

From the look of the [tags](http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbosstm/tags/) JBossTM doesn't go beyond 4.12.0 so I think I can be pretty sure in saying that 5.1.0 is the same 5.1.0 as JBoss itself.

Is there a way to reliably get the correct version of the source code for this (or any other) library? It seems to me that sometimes the manifest contains the version of the library, sometimes the version of the server, which isn't very helpful.

Thanks in advance

Rich

Comment: Further to this, I think I have found the information by going into the JBoss 5.1.0 release notes where one of the Component Upgrade bugs is https://jira.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-6851 - Update to transactions 4.6.1.GA - but I'm leaving this open for now just in case there is a better way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to this, I think I have found the information by going into the JBoss 5.1.0 release notes where one of the Component Upgrade bugs is jira.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-6851 - Update to transactions 4.6.1.GA